# OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the FBO extension is required- LibGDX Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl, libgdx

I start using LibGDX from a month ago & It was working perfectly! But yesterday, after updating to Java 8, I ran two desktop projects that used to work , it showed me this error:

> OpenGL is not supported by the video driver

I searched online & I found someone post this code:

```
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

Well, it works with one of the project, [zombie bird tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html) that I was studying , but with the other project It shows:

> OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the FBO extension is required. OpenGL version: 1.1.0
>   Microsoft Corporation
>   GDI Generic
>   1.1.0

P.S: My device OpenGl version is: 3.1, 
Intel HD Graphics 3000 , 
LibGDX Release: 1.6.5 , 
& I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: On windows, the GDI software renderer only supports OpenGL 1.1, so this will not be an alternative for you.

Comment: But I was working before & it was working with no single error! I did nothing to the code except updating Java. could GDI run OpenGl 1.1 after 3.1?!

Comment: Sorry, maybe my first comment was too unclear. By setting allowSoftwareOpenGL to true, you force the application to use the GDI software renderer, which only supports OpenGL 1.1. But I don't know why it doesn't work without this line

Comment: Ah! I got it now! So, it's the GDI. I'll try to find a solution for this issue or I'll just use an older version of LibGDX! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I wasn't able to find a real solution for the problem but as long as this issue is because of your Windows GDI, it will remain only on your PC not the other pc's! 
So, as a solution, you can keep testing on your android device or your emulator! You'll have the same result on your android project.

UPDATE:

Find the real solution! You only need to uninstall Java 8 & re-install Java 7!
Seems that Java 8 doesn't support or get alone with Libgdx :p

Comment: Well, Java 8 is required for Eclipse Neon :(

Comment: @Ajay switch to Android Studio, it's more better & works perfectly :)

Comment: I hate Android studio, I just like eclipse so much more because it can be used for more than just Android.

Comment: @Ajay Well, I run a libgdx desktop project on Android Studio..
Android Studio has many good features Eclipse doesn't have..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Eclipse Neon+ (Not sure about Mars) you need Java 8, so a better solution is to just change the JRE in the Java Build Path to Java 7. This will fix it.